# META-INF folder missing from the module subfolder when trying to run an executable JAR

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, executable-jar

Context: I have two systems, one which has a custom kernel and one with a normal Ubuntu 20.04 distribution. The end goal is to try and run Java on the custom kernel. Until now I have managed to run a simple HelloWorld class. The next step I am trying is to build a simple HelloWorld spring boot app and to try and run it. On both systems, I have the same OpenJDK version (`openjdk 18-internal 2022-03-15`).

So, what I have been trying: I have an IntelliJ project on my Ubuntu machine, with Spring Boot and Maven. I package this application as an executable jar with `mvn clean package`. The resulting `.jar` works fine on this machine. I then move the `.jar` file to the custom kernel machine, it starts running, but at some point I get this error:

```
Error getting resources from path
Reported exception:
Caused by: java.nio.file.FileSystemException: modules/java.rmi/META-INF/services/ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.Configurator: No such file
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:100)
```

I checked the `OpenJDK` file structure on both machines and it is the same. (I have not found that exact META-INF folder even on the Ubuntu machine)

My question is what exactly is that `META-INF` folder inside the `modules` jdk folder and when or how exactly it gets created. Shouldn't the `.jar` file contain everything it need to run?

Some additional info:

If I unpack the generated `.jar` file I get a `META-INF` and a `BOOT-INF` folder but the path does not correspond. The `pom.xml` file I used looks like this:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.5</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>hello-openjdk</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>hello-openjdk</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Edit:

Directory layout when I try to run the app:

```
├── hello-openjdk-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
├── bin
├── conf
├── include
├── lib
├── man
├── modules
├── _optimize_image_exec.cmdline
├── _optimize_image_exec.log
├── _optimize_image_exec.marker
└── release
```

OpenJDK `jdk` folder + `app.jar` file

Directory layout of the project from which the jar gets created:

```
├── hello-openjdk.iml
├── HELP.md
├── mvnw
├── mvnw.cmd
├── pom.xml
├── src
│   ├── main
│   │   ├── java
│   │   └── resources
│   └── test
│       └── java
└── target
    ├── BOOT-INF
    │   ├── classes
    │   ├── classpath.idx
    │   ├── layers.idx
    │   └── lib
    ├── classes
    │   ├── application.properties
    │   └── com
    ├── generated-sources
    │   └── annotations
    ├── generated-test-sources
    │   └── test-annotations
    ├── hello-openjdk-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
    ├── hello-openjdk-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar.original
    ├── maven-archiver
    │   └── pom.properties
    ├── maven-status
    │   └── maven-compiler-plugin
    ├── META-INF
    │   ├── MANIFEST.MF
    │   └── maven
    ├── org
    │   └── springframework
    ├── surefire-reports
    │   ├── com.example.helloopenjdk.HelloOpenjdkApplicationTests.txt
    │   └── TEST-com.example.helloopenjdk.HelloOpenjdkApplicationTests.xml
    └── test-classes
        └── com
```

`BOOT-INF` and `META-INF` are extracted from the `.jar` file. So, if I want to run the `hello-openjdk-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar` on another machine with the same Java version, what do I have to copy?

Comment: Please show your directory layout...

Comment: I don't find `src/main/java` `src/test/java` `src/main/resources` and `src/test/resource`... (follow conventions!!) What is `modules`? What is `bin`? Please check https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html

Comment: Those are the project directories, I do have that structure, but once the executable jar is created what do those matter? The executable jar should be a standalone executable independent of the project directory, it should be portable. Isn't that how it should be? So, the executable jar is created from a project that has the directory structure that you pointed to, do I need to also copy that whole structure to the other machine?

Comment: Maven is based on conventions (which includes the directory layout).. and no you don't have that layout... Is the shows directory inside your target directory. please complete the information otherwise it's not possible to help...

Comment: I have added the project directory structure.

Comment: If you want to run your jar file you have to use the original `hello-openjdk-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar` via `java -jar hello-openjdk-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar`. What I don't understand is the `Directory layout when I try to run the app:...` ? How and why do you build that? That's spring boot application which contains everything in the jar file ???

Comment: So, the `app.jar` file in the first directory layout is the same as the `hello-openjdk-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar`. I just renamed it. The jar I build with `mvn clean package`. I want to take that jar and run it on another machine so that `Directory layout when I try to run the app` is the layout on that machine which only contain the JDK (that you can see in the layout) and the jar.

Comment: `java  -jar hello-openjdk-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar` works fine on the machine I generate it even if I change the directory. But when I try to run it on another machine I get that error.